# How to read/convert pcm,embedded-shorten encoding?

Tags: ubuntu, audio, wav, file-format, pcm

I have a few SPHERE files whose encoding does not seem to be supported. Here is the header :

```
NIST_1A
1024
sample_rate -i 22050
channel_count -i 2
sample_n_bytes -i 2
sample_count -i 63475939
sample_byte_format -s2 10
sample_coding -s26 pcm,embedded-shorten-v2.00
sample_checksum -i 33942
end_head
```

Sox doesn't seem to support the pcm,embedded-shorten encoding. Any other softwares/suggestions to convert this file to wav format?

Answer (score 3):

You could try sph2pipe. It's not very well maintained. Currently the source code and a Windows build can be downloaded here:

```
http://www.openslr.org/resources/3/sph2pipe_v2.5.tar.gz
```

I was able to compile it in Linux with the following command:

```
gcc -o sph2pipe sph2pipe.c shorten_x.c file_headers.c -lm
```

To convert file.sph to wav format:

```
sph2pipe -f rif file.sph file.wav
```

Comment: Documentation on sph2pipe options and usage: https://github.com/foundintranslation/Kaldi/blob/master/tools/sph2pipe_v2.5/sph2pipe.c

Answer (score 0):

sph2pipe does not support certain variants of 'shorten' compression, so you may want to try piping just the non-header portion of the file to ffmpeg.